# How to save mp4 in sql server c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

**How to save mp4 in sql server c#.**
Which data type we should use in sql server.

Comment: [`FILESTREAM`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is one option

Comment: then in DB which datatype?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would be better saving the MP4 on the server and storing the location of the file in the database.

Comment: Why would that be better?

Comment: Check out the top answer here that explains why very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: And check the comments under that answer and the rest of the answers for why _"don't store files in a database"_ isn't a definitive answer. You don't know OP's requirements, so you can't say any solution _"would be better"_. Sure, OP is talking about video files which should give some insight, but it's unanswerable in its current form anyway.

Comment: Its subjective and there are many considerations as to which is appropriate, Also see [programmers.se Q](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database) (and the linked dba.se question)

Comment: It impacts on the performance of the DB

Comment: I have requirement to store in db..that also in mp4

Answer (score 0):

A `BLOB` stores binary data, so an time you have something you don't think fits into the databases defined type you can use a [BLOB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb895234.aspx).